# SharePoint 2010 Back up strategy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup

We have a setup here with SharePoint 2010 where every website is created as a separate web application for making backup and recovery easier, however I see the following issues about this approach:

- Lack of a structured hierarchy making management more difficult
- Manual management of the hierarchy in the front-end

What are your views on this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st thing, having one site collection a web app is really bad idea. Because for each site collection you creating more web apps, which put more load on the SharePoint Farm, make the tough job to monitor, maintaining also too hard. Same thing with backup. Their is limit from MSFT that you have 10 app pools and 20 Web Apps per farm.

What I would recommend, Create One Web App and put all site collections in that Web app but you can put each site collection into own content DB. that's make life easier.

Now take the backup of the content DB regularly so in case of the DR you just simply need to restore the DB.

Comment: It should be noted the boundary is 300 content DBs if you are going to suggest that.

Comment: Also 10 pools/20 web apps isn't a hard limit. You can certainly go quite a bit above that with the appropriate amount of memory/CPU. It's just not a very good architecture for performance.

Answer (score 0):

A backup strategy we had employed was every night the content databases were backed as well as the individual site collections. Our topology in that environment was only using about 5 content databases so this gave us flexibility if someone botched their site collection, we didn't need to restore the whole content db. It also allowed for an easy port to a dev or qa environment to recover a file or to begin testing new features or designs.

With farms being so wildly different, I think it'll come down to what works best for you and how you need to recover. I don't think there will be one best answer here.

Comment: @pirateErc Thanks for your response, does your setup create a separate web app per website request? Basically we have an intranet and each departmental website has been created as a web app rather than under a single site collection. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: No, we don't. That will scale horribly and perform poorly like Waqas mentions. We have 3 web apps, one for my sites, one for dedicated apps and one for collaboration where most all sites reside.